# OnKeyListener in Android not firing an event (Volume key) inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, keylistener

I have an Android Application inside a fragment, I am trying to get volume keys pressed event, but the event doesn't fire off.

I tried setting a breakpoint at onKey() method, it never went there.

Code below:-

```
import android.view.View.OnKeyListener;
 public class ExampleFragment extends Fragment implements OnKeyListener {
     @Override
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
         if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
             //to do code goes in here
             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: you didn't bind it with anything

Comment: Is it possible to bind it to Button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set the `Fragment` as the `KeyListener` to anything. There needs to be a `View` registered to submit `KeyEvent`s to.

In your `Fragment`, try something like:

```
@Nullable @Override public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Create an EditText we want to Listen to.
    EditText e = new EditText(getActivity());
    // Assert this Fragment was the KeyListener.
    e.setOnKeyListener(this);
    // Return the View.         
    return e;
}
```

In an ideal world, a `Button` should not be responsible for *listening* to `KeyEvent`s. It should only deal with clicks and presses, since this is how a `Button` behaves in the real world. In general, you should avoid giving any kind of graphical objects application-specific knowledge, it should be up to the application to decide what to do, and update the UI accordingly.

This kind of architecture commonly comes in the form of the [Model View Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129921/what-is-mvc-model-view-controller).

Instead, you might want to try overriding `onKeyDown` in the `Fragment`'s owning `Activity`, and routing that to a corresponding method in the `Fragment`.

See this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12210906/fragment-activity-catch-onkeydown-and-use-in-fragment).

Comment: An `OnKeyListener` can be applied to *any* `View`.

Comment: ` startButton.setOnkeyListener(this)` I added in the code but still, it didn't capture the event for me.

Comment: It would be something like `startButton.setOnKeyListener(this)`; be wary of the capitalisation. If this answer has helped you, please consider marking the question as answered. :-)

Comment: Could you also let me know if I bind it to a button, will it call the on click function of Button?

Comment: Yes, if you program it that way. ;)

Comment: Could you show me to an Example, how to make it work?

Comment: Not unless you mark this question as answered, and post a new question.

Comment: My question isn't solved yet pal. this is what I have at the moment. Exactly the way we bind any listener, the question still remains the same, how to am I suppose to get the event fired off  `startButton.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
   @Override
   public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)){
     startButtonPressed();
             return true;
          }
    return false;
   }
  });`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, onKeyListener works right in the one Fragment but it doesn't work in the another. I found out that it depends on the type of keyboard. 
I had set on the EditText inputType="text" and it began to work. It is a miracle. I really can't understand what is going on. In my case problem arise in Huawei, on the genymotion Error didn't arise.

```
   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:inputType="text"
    />
```

Comment: I used virtual keypad input type, though my edit text input property wasn't set. I had to hack it with interface overriding a method to work on two different fragments.